# Maven returns unknown lifecycle error when invoked from an sh file

Tags: bash, shell, maven

I am running the following command, from a sh file.

```
echo "This is job" $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
#! Command line that we want to run:
SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID=0
varData='mvn -e clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=App.Main -Dexec.args="wikiLineSPlits/wiki-004/ wiki-004-'$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID'.txt wiki-004-'$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID' wikiOuts/  wiki-004"'
echo $varData
$varData
```

Here, running the code results in the following output:

```
mvn -e clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=App.Main -Dexec.args="wikiLineSPlits/wiki-004/ wiki-004-0.txt wiki-004-0 wikiOuts/ wiki-004"

Unknown lifecycle phase "wiki-004-0.txt"
```

But if I copy-paste the output from `echo $varData` to my terminal screen, then the program executes scuesfully. I am not sure what is the source of error. Any help would be appreciated.

Output from `echo $varData`:

```
 mvn -e clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=App.Main -Dexec.args="/home/ak2329/rds/hpc-work/feverDataset/wikiLineSPlits/wiki-004/ wiki-004-0.txt wiki-004-0 /home/ak2329/rds/hpc-work/feverDataset/wikiOuts/ wiki-004"
```

Comment: I am suspecting this has something to do with the way I am concatenating the values in the string $varData. But, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
$(echo $varData)
```

As the last line in your script

Comment: Thanks. However, doesn't directly using the command a better option, instead of saving it to a variable and then using `$echo`, from a reading accessibility point of view? Please refer to my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that *each* stage of your maven command line is being passed the `-Dexec` arguments, and neither `clean` nor `compile` knows what to do with them. If you rewrite your command as to stages

```
mvn clean compile
```

and
mvn exec

and only pass the `-Dexec` args to the second stage, then you should not get those errors.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to directly use the shell command, instead of storing it to a variable.

```
mvn -e clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=App.Main -Dexec.args="wikiLineSPlits/wiki-004/ wiki-004-'$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID'.txt wiki-004-'$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID' wikiOuts/  wiki-004"
```

Previously the command used was:

```
varData='mvn -e clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=App.Main -Dexec.args="wikiLineSPlits/wiki-004/ wiki-004-'$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID'.txt wiki-004-'$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID' wikiOuts/  wiki-004"'
echo $varData
```

Comment: of course, there are often many ways to the same destination